# Find the particular solution that satisfies the initial condition

Tags: calculus

This is how I am going about it

$yy'-e^{x}=0$  ;   $y(0)= 4$

I put it in standard form

$\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{e^{x}}y$=0

$P(x)=e^{x}$

$Q(x)=0$

$I(x) = e^{\int e^{x}}$= ?

I'm not sure if I am doing it correctly but if so, what would I(x) come out to be?

Comment: **Hint:** This is a Separable Equation. Separate, integrate, solve for the constant. You have $ \displaystyle  \int y~dy = \int e^x~dx$.

Comment: And its **not** L.D.E., See you have $y$ in denominator!

Comment: @Moo Oh I feel dumb, I got it now thank you!

Comment: Question: So any time I cannot separate this equation will the answer always be solved in linear equation?

Comment: No. Another method may be required and there are many. It truly depends on the problem. Some problems have many approaches to solve while others a single approach and some - no analytical approach - go numerical. Bottom line, depends on the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{ydy}{dx} - \exp^x =0$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\exp^x}{y}$$
$$\int(y)dy = \int(\exp^x)dx$$
$$\frac{y^{2}}{2} = \exp^x + c $$ 
$$y^2 = 2 \exp^x + c_{}1$$ where c_{1} = 2c
$$y = \surd (2(\exp^x) + c_{1})$$ 
$$ now  y(0) = 4 $$
$$ c_{1} = 14 $$
$$so the answer is y = \surd(2(\exp^x) + 14) $$

Answer (score 1):

$yy'=e^{x}$,

$\implies \frac{1}{2}(y^{2})'=e^{x}$ so $(y^{2})'=2e^{x}$

$\implies y^{2}=2e^{x}+C$.

Now $y(0)= 4$, $4 = 2+C \implies C = 2.$

Thus the particular solution that satisfies the initial condition is $y^{2}=2e^{x}+2$.